# Return number from NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsstring

I have NSString like this: @"text 932".

How I can return number from this string. Number is always at the end of string, but i can' t use stringWithRange, because number don' t have constant length. So I'm seeking for better method.

I aslo want' know how to return number from string like this @"text 3232 text". I aslo don' t know position of number.

There is any function that find number in string ?

Comment: Take a look at NSScanner: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, now i know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work for both strings

```
NSString *myString = @"text 3232 text";

//Create a scanner with the string
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myString];

//Create a character set that includes all letters, whitespaces, and newlines
//These will be used as skip tokens
NSMutableCharacterSet *charactersToBeSkipped = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc]init];

[charactersToBeSkipped formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
[charactersToBeSkipped formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:charactersToBeSkipped];
[charactersToBeSkipped release];

//Create an int to hold the number   
int i;

//Do the work
if ([scanner scanInt:&i]) {

    NSLog(@"i = %d", i);
}
```

The output of the `NSLog` is

```
i = 3232
```

## EDIT

To handle decimals:

```
float f;

if ([scanner scanFloat:&f]) {

   NSLog(@"f = %f", f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Updated to test whether there is a match or not, and also to handle negative/decimal numbers

```
NSString *inputString=@"text text -9876.234 text";
NSString *regExprString=@"-{0,1}\\d*\\.{0,1}\\d+";
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExprString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch=[regex firstMatchInString:inputString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, inputString.length)].range;
if(rangeOfFirstMatch.length>0){
    NSString *firstMatch=[inputString substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
    NSLog(@"firstmatch:%@",firstMatch);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"No Match");
}
```

**Original:**
Here is a solution that uses regular expressions:

```
NSString *inputString=@"text text 0123456 text";
NSString *regExprString=@"[0-9]+";
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExprString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];
NSString *firstMatch=[inputString substringWithRange:[regex firstMatchInString:inputString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, inputString.length)].range];
NSLog(@"%@",firstMatch);
```

output is:
0123456

If you want an actual integer from that, you can add:

```
NSInteger i=[firstMatch integerValue];
NSLog(@"%d",i);
```

Output is then: 123456

Comment: With this strategy, how do you tell the difference between a 0 integer value and the 0 that is assigned to i when there is no match?

Comment: Also, you need to adjust the Regex expression to account for negative integers.

Comment: Joseph, that's the beauty of regular expression, it is powerful enough to handle all kind of scenario, let me edit my answer to handle negative and decimal numbers.

Comment: I don't disagree that Regex is powerful.  If you are going to update your answer, don't forget to handle if the text is right up against the number, in the case of @"text0123456text".

Comment: Joseph, my last edit was already working for your specific case. What I like about regular expressions is that they are used in most languages, therefore there is a ton of tutorials and examples on how to build them for specific cases, whether you just want to match a number, or a phone number, a SSN, etc...